# why do i get an error which says invalid, about this code?

Tags: python

why do i get an error whitch says invalid, about this code?

```
line = input("Enter an integer number : ")
num = int(line)   
if (num % 2 == 0):  
    print("The number is even" ,num)   
else:   
    print("The number is odd ", num)
```

Comment: Can you format your code so it truly represents how it was executed as indentation matters in python, to format code for SO select the code and press `ctrl+k`

Comment: There are still indentation issues. Could you fix it ? Otherwise, we can't help you. Could you paste your error, too ?

Comment: Your code should work with the proper indentation.

Comment: Once formatted well it seems to works perfectly.

Comment: You should also include the full traceback, what exactly is your error? My guess is an `IndentationError` if this really is your indentation or a `ValueError` if the user passes a letter to `input()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent your code properly:

```
line = input("Enter an integer number : ")
num = int(line)   
if (num % 2 == 0):  
    print("The number is even" ,num)   
else:   
    print("The number is odd ", num)
```

If you're fairly new to python, a good point to start could be the documentation to learn about Block indentation.

Another problem could arise if its not possible to change the input within the variable `line` into an integer with `int(line)`. You might want to have a look how to work with [try and except](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html) to handle errors like that.